# Express + Node Route With Multiple Parameters in Query String

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am building an API in Node and am struggling to figure something out. Namely, I know how to build routes of the type `/api/:paramA/:paramB`. In this case, there are two parameters.

The code would be something like this:

```
router.get('/test/:paramA/:paramB', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' + req.params.paramA + req.params.paramB});   
});
```

How could one build a route that would respond at something like `/api?paramA=valueA&paramB=valueB`?

Answer (score 17):

To use this URL in a route with Express:

```
 /api?paramA=valueA&paramB=valueB
```

You do this:

```
router.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.paramA);     // valueA
    console.log(req.query.paramB);     // valueB
    console.log(req.query.paramC);     // undefined (doesn't exist)
});
```

Query parameters are parsed into the [`req.query` object](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).  If the query parameter name does not exist in the query string, then that property will not exist on the query.query object and trying to read it will return `undefined`.  Keep in mind that all values will be strings.  If you desire them to be a number or some other data type, then you have to parse them into that other type.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using this. This code did exactly what I set out to do in the original question.

```
router.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    if(typeof req.query.paramA !== 'undefined' && typeof req.query.paramB !== 'undefined') {
    let paramA = req.query.paramA,   
        paramB = req.query.paramB;
    //do something with paramA and paramB
   }
});
```

Comment: This is not the recommend way to do this.  `req.query` is the proper place to access parsed parameters from the query string.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing this out! I copied the code wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It`s easier to define url parameters in router .

> Example url : http://www.example.com/api/users/3&0

```
router.get('/api/users/:id&:pending', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  console.log(req.params.pending);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain about the GET parameters that are being passed, so you could easily do it like this:

```
router.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    if(typeof req.params.paramA !== 'undefined' && typeof req.params.paramB !== 'undefined') {
    let paramA = req.params.paramA,   
        paramB = req.params.paramB;
    //do something with paramA and paramB
   }
});
```

Comment: What if I need to check whether both of the parameters are present?

Comment: That is, is this still a solid solution for that case?

Comment: I had to do the following to get it working: `let paramA = req.param('paramA'), paramB = req.param('paramB');
`

Comment: Quoted from [Express 4.x API](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) -
 "req.param(name [, defaultValue]) is
Deprecated.   Use either req.params, req.body or req.query, as applicable. 
Direct access to req.body, req.params, and req.query should be favoured for clarity - unless you truly accept input from each object.."

Comment: I am not sure why that happens but your version returns empty variables for me. I believe i have the latest stable Express installed.

Comment: This answer seems to be missing `:paramA` and `:paramB` from the route definition.

Comment: I would think it should be just like the OP had it: `router.get('/test/:paramA/:paramB', function(req, res) {...}`.  If `:paramA` and `:paramB` are not in the route definition, then `req.params.paramA` and `req.params.paramB` will not be present.  It is the route definition that causes them to get parsed and put into the `req.params` object.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, but I was looking to get the route of the following form: `/api?paramA=valueA&paramB=valueB`

Comment: @jfriend00 My question asks specifically for that. Read the very last sentence :)